# Why docker-compose up command always falling back to default spring boot profile?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-profiles

Why docker-compose up command always falling back to default spring boot profile though we have override it in application.properties file . like

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=schemaDevelopment
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for setting the active profile in the `application.properties` file is wrong, example: `spring.profiles.active=production`

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles

The format `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` is used when you set the profile via an environmental variable

Comment: I tried this but still it is falling back to default spring boot profile